# Get keycode from key name in XCB?

Tags: linux, x11, xcb

I'm currently working a small XCB application, but I'm having a hard time finding an alternative for the following routine:

```
XKeysymToKeycode(display, XStringToKeysym("Tab"))
```

I managed to get the keycode via `xmodmap -pke` and hardcoded into the application, but I'm pretty sure this is going to cause me problems down the road (different hardware? different distros?).

Is there any way of getting the keycode from its name in XCB?

Comment: Relevant mailing list threads: [xcb equivalent of XKeysymToKeycode?](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xcb/2010-October/006508.html) (from 2010) and [XStringToKeysym() XCB equivalent?](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xcb/2008-March/003344.html) (from 2008). The former does give an answer, but the latter says that there's no equivalent to corresponding function, and current [xcb.fdo page](https://xcb.freedesktop.org/XCBToDoKeyboard/) also has `XStringToKeysym` marked as TODO. So I guess there's no nice way to achieve what you want with XCB alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure that the library you are looking for is libxkbcommon: https://xkbcommon.org/

I *believe* the function you are looking for *might be* `xkb_state_key_get_one_sym`: https://xkbcommon.org/doc/current/group__state.html#ga47311e7268935dd2fe3e6ef057a82cb0
This function gets a keyboard state and a keycode and provides a keysyms.

Edit: Whoops, sorry. I got it backwards. `xkb_state_key_get_one_sym` turns a keycode into a keysym and not the other way around. Also, I cannot find any function for doing the direction that you want and somehow "the question" does not seem sensible to me.

For example: To enter =, I need to press multiple keys, so which keycode do you want here?

The code in Xlib for `XKeysymToKeycode` just iterates over all keysyms and tries to find some match (ignoring the level it found this match). This can also be done with `xkb_keymap_key_get_syms_by_level`:

```
KeyCode
XKeysymToKeycode(
    Display *dpy,
    KeySym ks)
{
    register int i, j;

    if ((! dpy->keysyms) && (! _XKeyInitialize(dpy)))
    return (KeyCode) 0;
    for (j = 0; j < dpy->keysyms_per_keycode; j++) {
    for (i = dpy->min_keycode; i <= dpy->max_keycode; i++) {
        if (KeyCodetoKeySym(dpy, (KeyCode) i, j) == ks)
        return i;
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can i replicate XStringToKeysym, which is the most difficult part?

Comment: I do not know for sure, but from the code of `XKeysymToKeycode`, I would expect you need to loop through all keycodes and levels and check via `xkb_keymap_key_get_syms_by_level` if you found a match.